# The number of seven digit integers, with sum of the digits equal to 10 and formed by using the digits 1, 2 and 3 only, is

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-theorem

I solved it using the regular combination method taking the two cases as 1,1,1,1,1,2,3 and 1,1,1,1,2,2,2.

But how do you solve it using multinomial theorem?

Comment: Simple computer search:  $77$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is perhaps an alternative approach: Let us think about how many ways one can form **three** digit numbers using the digits $1$, $2$, and $3$, such that the result has digital sum **7**. The possibilities can be listed exhaustively:

$$133, 313, 331, 233, 323, 332$$

There are a total of **six** such possibilities.

Next, consider (for reasons perhaps not yet clear) the following:

$$(x^1 + x^2 + x^3)^3 = x^9 + 3x^8 + 6x^7 + 7x^6 + 6x^5 + 3x^4 + x^3$$

Since we only have the digits $1$, $2$, and $3$, the only exponents that apppear within the parentheses are precisely these; i.e., all you see is $x^1$, $x^2$, and $x^3$. Moreover, since we are trying to look at **three** digit numbers, the expression in parentheses is raised to the **third** power. Finally, we are wondering about how many of the resulting three digit numbers have digital sum **seven**; indeed, looking at the expanded form, the coefficient of $x^7$ gives the answer: $6$ (as listed above).

What's going on here? Try tinkering around to see how these exponents interact with one another. As to your particular problem, you can expand $(x^1 + x^2 + x^3)^7$ and check the coefficient of $x^{10}$; as remarked in a comment above, or as you can find yourself using e.g. WolframAlpha, it is $77$.

Comment: (**FWIW:** The method outlined here is motivated by generating functions, but is essentially a disguised version of the **multinomial theorem**...)

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. Thank you.

Comment: @TheRoom You're welcome! It is a technique I first learned by making $6$ by $6$ addition tables for outcomes of rolling two six-sided dice; but, by using this same sort of ["partial products" area] model for multiplying $x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6$ one finds those dice rolling *addition* outcomes written as exponents resulting from *multiplication*. A similar technique can be used to find the unique answer around [Sicherman dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicherman_dice)!

Answer (score 3):

There are only two integer partitions of $10$ of length 7 formed from the digits $1,2,3$:  $\{ 3,2,1,1,1,1,1 \}$ and $\{ 2,2,2,1,1,1,1 \}$.  The number of ways you can form numbers from the first set can be computed using a multinomial:

${7! \over 1! 1! 5!} = 42$

and for the second set is

${7! \over 3! 4!} = 35$

so the total is $77$.

Confirmation using *Mathematica*:

```
 Length@Select[Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 7], Total[#] == 10 &]
```

(* 
77
*)

Comment: Same method I did. But I was looking for a multinomial theorem based approach:)

Answer (score 2):

The number of solutions is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(x+x^2+x^3)^7$ which is the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1-x^3)^7(1-x)^{-7}$. Only the first two terms : $1$ and $-7x^3$ are of relevance to us since the other terms have higher powers of $x$. If we select $1$, we'd have to select the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1-x)^{-7}$. I leave it to you to find the other coefficient out.

The answer is :
$$
\binom{9}{6}-7=77
$$